# Cannot write data from Docker Container running julia application to local storage

Tags: docker, dockerfile, julia, storage

I have query related to docker container writing and reading from local disk.
For example , I have a julia application, which is writing and reading the processed data using the following set of functions:

```
function store(data::Array, ref::String)
   name = test_folder
   try
     create_dir(mkdir("$(homedir())/$name"))
   catch
     @warn "directory exists"
   end
   
   open("$(mkpath("$(joinpath(homedir(),"test_folder"))\\$ref\\$ref.jls", "w") do io
       serialize(io, data)
   end
end

function read_storage(ref)
   data = open(joinpath(homedir(), "test_folder\\$ref\\$ref.jls")) do io
       data = deserialize(io)
       return data
   end
   return data
end
```

To containerized this app (which is exposing on port 8000), I have created a dockerfile as shown below:

```
FROM julia:1.6
WORKDIR /home

ENV Version 1
ADD . /home

RUN julia app.jl

ENTRYPOINT ["julia", "-e", "app.run()"
```

However, upon running this container and exposing it to certain port, this doesn't write the data on my local `homedir()` and also even when i tried to enter the container in `exec` mode the `test_folder` cannot be found anywhere.

May I ask what could be causing this issue ?
Thanks, look forward to the suggestions!

Comment: A container usually runs in an isolated filesystem, and can't write to your host home directory unless the operator specifically gives it the ability to.  "Home directory" isn't usually well-defined inside a container.  You also might have trouble if you're using Windows style `path\subdirectory` paths in a Linux container, which expects forward slashes `/path/subdirectory`.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the response, I changed the path to linux style. :100
May I ask how can i give the ability to the container to write it on local drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). For example on linux host:

```
docker -v $HOME/test_folder:/home/test_folder image_name
```

The path before `:` is the local host directory and the path defined after the `:` separator is the container directory path.